# using a jpanel in another class? (noob issue)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have the classes:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class MyTimer extends JFrame {
    static JButton quitButton;
    static JButton quit_2Button;
    public MyTimer() {

        initUI();

    }

    public static void random(){
        int x = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        int y = (int)(Math.random() * 150 + 1);
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        quitButton = new JButton("Press this to quit?");
        quitButton.setBounds(x, y, 200, 20);
    }
    public void initUI() {
        random();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

       getContentPane().add(panel);

       panel.setLayout(null);
       JButton quit_2Button = new JButton("Or maybe press this to quit!");
       quit_2Button.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 20);
       quit_2Button.setRolloverEnabled(true);
       quit_2Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
               System.exit(0);
          }
       });
       quitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
               finder.main(null);
          }
       });


       panel.add(quitButton);
       panel.add(quit_2Button);
       setTitle("Java");
       setSize(300, 200);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

, and

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.Timer;

    public class timer_run {
        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.remove(); //error here
            }
         };
        public static void main(String[] args) {


            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MyTimer ex = new MyTimer();
                    ex.setVisible(true);
                    new timer_run();

                }

            });

        }
         public timer_run() {
                Timer timer = new Timer(1000, al);
                timer.start();


    }
}
```

and I am trying to make it so that when actionlistener al is activated, `jpanel.remove(quit_2Button)` is called. The problem is, that whenever i try and do this it gives me the error "panel cannot be resolved". I assume the reason this is happening is because timer_run does not have access to the JPanel frame, but through various trial and error have not been able to fix this. Does anybody have any suggstions about what I could possibly do to let timer_run see the JPanel frame? thanks in advance, and please note I am a java noob, so make the answer as simple as you can, if possible?

Comment: As an aside: You probably shouldn't be extending `JFrame`...

Comment: what would you recommend I use instead?

Comment: Try an instance variable.

Comment: sorry... what is that?

Comment: You really should crack open your text book. From your questions, it looks like you're just guessing at how to program, and that won't work.

Comment: im sorry, I am trying to self-teach myself how to program... any specific resources you would recommend for me?

Comment: Buy a textbook, any will do, and start from the beginning. The Head First series might work well for you. Myself, I bought a bunch of used text books on the cheap, and then after learning what they held, used the online tutorials to learn the latest changes to Java.

Comment: awesome, looking into it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommendations:

- One class should not try to directly manipulate variables of another class.
- Instead have one class call public methods of the other class.
- To allow your second class to do that, you need to pass a reference of the first class's object into that of the second class. I suggest you do this via a constructor parameter.

For example

```
// class name should begin with an upper case letter
public class TimerRun {
  private MyTimer myTimer;


  public TimerRun(MyTimer myTimer) {
    this.myTimer = myTimer;
  }

  //.... 
}
```

Now the TimerRun class can call public methods on the MyTimer object held by myTimer by calling, `myTimer.someMethod()`

Comment: @quixotrykd: by using the concepts that I have shown you above. Please try and see what you can come up with.